# Calls to Dispatcher.register return `undefined`

Tags: flux, jestjs

new to Jest and having trouble with getting up and running. When calling `Dispatcher.register`, all I get is `undefined`.

I'm running Node.js 5.7.0 and Jest 0.9.2.

The following test fails:

**BookedServicesStore-test.js**:

```
jest.unmock("../BookedServicesStore");
jest.unmock("object-assign");

describe("BookedServicesStore", () => {
  let BookedServicesStore;
  let AppDispatcher;

  beforeEach(() => {
    BookedServicesStore = require("../BookedServicesStore");
    AppDispatcher = require("../../dispatcher/AppDispatcher");
  });

  it("has a dispatch token", () => {
    expect(BookedServicesStore.dispatchToken).not.toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

---

**BookedServicesStore.js**:

```
import AppDispatcher from "../dispatcher/AppDispatcher";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
import assign from "object-assign";

const CHANGE_EVENT = "change";

const BookedServicesStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  emitChange() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  // ...
});

BookedServicesStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(action => {
  // ...
});

module.exports = BookedServicesStore;
```

---

**AppDispatcher.js**:

```
import { Dispatcher } from "flux";
module.exports = new Dispatcher();
```

Not sure what's going on here. What is it that I'm missing?